# MessagePort postMessage back pressure

Tags: node.js, queue, worker, node-worker-threads

I have a large set of jobs to run. The rate of execution would be CPU-limited (serialization/deserialization, etc.) if run single-threaded. I would like to improve throughput by partitioning the jobs across a set of node worker threads. The problem is that it is easy to generate jobs faster than they are consumed by the workers. The set of jobs is large and cannot fit in memory. So if the producer gets ahead of the consumers, then the process fails because of running out of memory.

Here is a working example. It crashes after producing about 3000 jobs on my computer when node is configured with a minimal heap `--max-old-space-size=4`.

```
// node 16, 8 cpus
// node --max-old-space-size=4 oom.js
// crashes after producing 3000 jobs

const os = require("os");
const { Worker, parentPort, isMainThread, threadId } = require("worker_threads");

// Produce jobs quickly
async function main() {
  const workers = os.cpus().map(() => new Worker(__filename));

  let id = 0;
  async function* generateJobs() {
    while (id < 100_000) {
      const message = {
        id,
        data: "0".repeat(100_000)
      };
      yield message;
      if (id % 1000 === 0) console.log("produced", message.id);

      id++;
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1));
    }
  }

  for await (const history of generateJobs()) {
    workers[0].postMessage(history);

    // Rotate workers
    workers.push(workers.shift());
  }

  workers.forEach(w => w.postMessage("exit"));
  const workerExits = workers.map(w => new Promise(resolve => w.on("exit", resolve)));
  await Promise.all(workerExits);
}

// Consume jobs slowly
function worker() {
  parentPort.on("message", message => {
    if (message === "exit") {
      console.log("finish", threadId);
      parentPort.close();
      return;
    }
    if (message.id % 1000 === 0) console.log("worker", threadId, "started", message.id);
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e8; i++) {} // Simulate a executing a CPU-bound job.
    if (message.id % 1000 === 0) console.log("worker", threadId, "finished", message.id);
  });
}

if (isMainThread) {
  main();
} else {
  worker();
}
```

Is there an in-process queue that works with node worker threads? The key is to provide back pressure on the producer, to limit the number queued jobs to a reasonable quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve the problem. When a worker requests a job, the producer generates it and sends it to the requesting worker. Each worker buffers up a fixed number of jobs when it starts. After finishing each job, the worker requests the next job. The system has a maximum number of in-progress jobs. So the memory required is similarly bounded.

```
// node 16, 8 cpus
// node --max-old-space-size=4 rr
// finishes: 5444.60s user 13.14s system 735% cpu 12:21.98 total

const os = require("os");
const { Worker, parentPort, isMainThread, threadId } = require("worker_threads");

// Produce jobs quickly
async function main() {
  const workers = os.cpus().map(() => new Worker(__filename));

  let id = 0;
  async function* generateJobs() {
    while (id < 100_000) {
      const message = {
        id,
        data: "0".repeat(100_000)
      };
      yield message;
      if (id % 1000 === 0) console.log("produced", message.id);

      id++;
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1));
    }
  }

  const generator = generateJobs();
  workers.forEach(w =>
    w.on("message", async () => {
      const { value, done } = await generator.next();
      if (done) {
        w.postMessage("exit");
      } else {
        w.postMessage(value);
      }
    })
  );

  const workerExits = workers.map(w => new Promise(resolve => w.on("exit", resolve)));
  await Promise.all(workerExits);
}

// Consume jobs slowly
function worker() {
  parentPort.on("message", message => {
    if (message === "exit") {
      console.log("exit", threadId);
      parentPort.close();
      return;
    }
    if (message.id % 1000 === 0) console.log("worker", threadId, "started", message.id);
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e8; i++) {} // Simulate a executing a CPU-bound job.
    if (message.id % 1000 === 0) console.log("worker", threadId, "finished", message.id);
    parentPort.postMessage("ready"); // after one job finishes, ask for the next job
  });

  // Buffer 10 unstarted jobs, to make sure the worker stays busy.
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    parentPort.postMessage("ready");
  }
}

if (isMainThread) {
  main();
} else {
  worker();
}
```

Another way to solve the problem is to implement a queue using SharedArrayBuffer. In this case, Atomics wait and notify would take the place of MessagePort postMessage. The SharedArrayBuffer queue would probably have less overhead. On the other hand it would be more complicated to implement, and there would likely be stricter limitations on the message objects.